# httpd2.2 using reverse proxy with RewriteCond goes into infinite loop

Tags: mod-rewrite, infinite-loop, mod-proxy

I want to direct incoming requests that do not a specific cookie set (`c_cntry`) and the request URL does not have a country value as the first element in path to an internal service that will attempt to figure out the right setting of `c_cntry`.

But when I send something like `http://localhost:8085/something-to-do` in the browser, I get an endless recursion in my logs, and an eventual 502 Proxy Error in the browser. The logs seem to show that `localhost:9999` given in ProxyPass directive is not being touched.

Will greatly appreciate your help in resolving this problem.

**httpd.conf**

```
RewriteLogLevel 3

RewriteRule .*\.php$ - [L]

#req doesnot have country nor is a good cookie present -- send it for geo-discovery

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(usa|india)/
RewriteCond %{HTTTP_COOKIE} !u_cntry=(usa|india)
RewriteRule (.*) /GeoDiscover?orig=($1)  [QSA,P]

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyTimeout 5
ProxyPass /GeoDiscover http://localhost:9999/GeoDiscover connectiontimeout=1 timeout=3 retry=3 
ProxyPassReverse /GeoDiscover http://localhost:9999/GeoDiscover
```

**REWRITE LOG:**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2011:12:07:58 +0530] "GET /ex2.php HTTP/1.1" 200 42 server:some-server-name file:C:/myhtdocs/ex2.php
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2011:12:08:02 +0530] "GET /something-to-do HTTP/1.1" 502 409 server:some-server-name file:proxy:http://localhost:8085/GeoDiscover?orig=(/something-to-do)
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2011:12:08:02 +0530] "GET /GeoDiscover?orig=(/something-to-do) HTTP/1.1" 502 401 server:some-server-name file:proxy:http://localhost:8085/GeoDiscover?orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/something-to-do)
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2011:12:08:02 +0530] "GET /GeoDiscover?orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/something-to-do) HTTP/1.1" 502 401 server:some-server-name file:proxy:http://localhost:8085/GeoDiscover?orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/something-to-do)
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2011:12:08:02 +0530] "GET /GeoDiscover?orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/something-to-do) HTTP/1.1" 502 401 server:some-server-name file:proxy:http://localhost:8085/GeoDiscover?orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/something-to-do) ...
```

**ACCESS LOG**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2011:12:07:58 +0530] "GET /ex2.php HTTP/1.1" 200 42 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1" "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2011:12:08:02 +0530] "GET /something-to-do HTTP/1.1" 502 409 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1" "127.0.0.1" "localhost:8085"
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2011:12:08:02 +0530] "GET /GeoDiscover?orig=(/something-to-do) HTTP/1.1" 502 401 "-" "Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1" "127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1" "localhost:8085, localhost:8085"
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2011:12:08:02 +0530] "GET /GeoDiscover?orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/something-to-do) HTTP/1.1" 502 401 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1" "127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1,
127.0.0.1" "localhost:8085, localhost:8085, localhost:8085, localhost:8085"
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2011:12:08:02 +0530] "GET /GeoDiscover?orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/something-to-do) HTTP/1.1" 502 401 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1" "127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1,
127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1" "localhost:8085, localhost:8085, localhost:8085, localhost:8085, localhost:8085" ...
```

**ERROR LOG**

```
[Sat Aug 06 12:08:02 2011] [debug] mod_proxy_htttp.c(56): proxy: HTTP: canonicalising URL //localhost:8085/GeoDiscover
[Sat Aug 06 12:08:02 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(1525): [client 127.0.0.1] proxy: *: found reverse proxy worker for http://localhost:8085/GeoDiscover?orig=(/something-to-do)
[Sat Aug 06 12:08:02 2011] [debug] mod_proxy.c(1015): Running scheme http handler (attempt 0)
[Sat Aug 06 12:08:02 2011] [debug] mod_proxy_htttp.c(1973): proxy: HTTP: serving URL http://localhost:8085/GeoDiscover?orig=(/something-to-do)
[Sat Aug 06 12:08:02 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(2011): proxy: HTTP: has acquired connection for (*)
[Sat Aug 06 12:08:02 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(2067): proxy: connecting http://localhost:8085/GeoDiscover?orig=(/something-to-do) to localhost:8085
[Sat Aug 06 12:08:02 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(2193): proxy: connected /GeoDiscover?orig=(/something-to-do) to localhost:8085
[Sat Aug 06 12:08:02 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(2444): proxy: HTTP: fam 2 socket created to connect to *
[Sat Aug 06 12:08:02 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(2576): proxy: HTTP: connection complete to 127.0.0.1:8085 (localhost)
[Sat Aug 06 12:08:02 2011] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(56): proxy: HTTP: canonicalising URL //localhost:8085/GeoDiscover^M [Sat Aug 06 12:08:02 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(1525): [client 127.0.0.1] proxy: *: found reverse proxy worker for http://localhost:8085/GeoDiscover?orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/something-to-do)
[Sat Aug 06 12:08:02 2011] [debug] mod_proxy.c(1015): Running scheme http handler (attempt 0
[Sat Aug 06 12:08:02 2011] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1973): proxy: HTTP: serving URL http://localhost:8085/GeoDiscover?orig=(/GeoDiscover)&orig=(/something-to-do)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one more rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/GeoDiscover
```

Then your rewrite rule should look like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(usa|india)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/GeoDiscover
RewriteCond %{HTTTP_COOKIE} !u_cntry=(usa|india)
RewriteRule (.*) /GeoDiscover?orig=($1)  [QSA,P]
```

**P.S.**
The **rewrite log** you have provided -- I do not think it is the actual rewrite log (at least I have not seen such format which mentions `GET`, `200` Response code etc before).

**P.P.S.**
When doing rewrite debugging -- better use `RewriteLogLevel 9` -- it produces more detailed output (possibly too much, so cannot be used on working server, but it tells exactly what is going on).

Comment: Hi L.O., thanks for the help. <br>
I had wrongly assumed that after applying an [L] rule
it'll automatically go thru proxy setup. It wasn't doing that
exactly (very perplexing, I still have to figure that out). 
So what I did instead was (i) change [L] to [N], and (ii) put a [P] rule
upfront as you had suggested. So it now looks like this: <br>

#rule 0<br>
RewriteRule (^GeoDiscover)(|/.*)$               http://localhost:9999/$1$2    [QSA,P] <br>


This worked out fine. I believe ProxyPassReverse will
still be in effect. 

Thanks
Dinesh<br>

PS: the logs are real!